# Add rows to GridView without Postback

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to add rows with web controls to a `GridView` using jquery?

Comment: GridView is rendered to a table, so in theory it is possible, although in practice this should be avoided as error prone. Can you explain why do you need that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add rows to a gridview using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415681/add-rows-to-a-gridview-using-javascript)

Comment: @Andrei What kinds of errors?

Comment: Many. First, this is going to be hard to maintain. Second, javascript object that represents gridview won't be aware of these rows. Third, gridview generates quite a bit of markup, so you will need to reproduce all this to keep your additions look the same, which is error prone on its own. Again, this is definitely not a general practice, so if you tell us your eventual goal we might be able to suggest a more robust approach

Answer (score 1):

Yes , gridview is rendered as table so you can insert new row

```
$('#<%=yourGridView.ClientID%>').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
```